# Using an object in a continuation, ensuring it isn't disposed before you need it

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, memory, dispose

In a Xamarin.iOS app, for various reasons we can't use `async`/`await`. Therefore, we are using `Task.ContinueWith`. The problem is that objects we rely on in the continuation are disposed before the continuation gets called.

```cs
using (UIImage image = // Somehow get the image)
{
    DoSomethingWith(image);
}

void DoSomethingWithImage(UIImage image)
{
    UploadImageAsync(image).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        // Image has been disposed by this point.
        DisplayResult(t.Result, image);
    });
}
```

I'm interested to get ideas on how to manage the above case. Options I've considered:

- Remove the `using` block, and let `image` go out of scope. This would be a bad idea, since `UIImage` could be quite large.
- Remove the `using`, and call `Dispose()` in the continuation. This feels error-prone, as whereever code like this exists, you're disposing the object far from where it was created.
- Wrap the call to `DoSomethingWithImage()` in a `Task.Run(() => DoSomethingWithImage(image)).ContinueWith(t => image.Dispose())`. So you have a continuation within a continuation. This feels over-complicated for this scenario.
- Any other options I'm overlooking?

Comment: Hi , you mean the `Continue` Task has beeb called before it runs ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all this a good question. Based on the mentioned options I think you have to change angel.

In your current implementation the scope of the `UIImage` is closely related to the `DoSomethingWith` method. In other words the retrieved image is only used inside that method. I can see two separate way, how this can evolve:

1. Introduce `DoSomethingElseWith` method
2. Get rid of the `DoSomethingWith` and "inline" the `UploadImage` and `DisplayResult`

In either way you would end up to have more than one methods inside in your `using` block. Which will indicate that the cleanup of the UIImage is none of the methods responsibility. In normal cases you would do this by `await`ing the last one and let the using block do its job, right?  If you can't await it then the most obvious choice for continuation is make use of `ContinueWith`.  (Others: `TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll`, `TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAny`, `Task.WhenAll`, `Task.WhenAny`, for [further info](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html)).

```
UIImage image = RetrieveImage();
var uploadJob = UploadImage(image);
var displayJob = uploadJob.ContinueWith((t => DisplayResult(t.Result, image)).Unwrap();
var disposeJob = displayJob.ContinueWith(_ => image.Dispose());
```

Alternatively you can use some short of signalling mechanism (sync primitive) to indicate when the last async operation has finished, like `AutoResetEvent`, `CountdownEvent`, `TaskComplitionSource`.

Your third option could be to use [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library). With that you can pipe together the small pieces and use [Completion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library#dataflow-block-completion) to initiate the dispose as your last action.